# Does the phone automatically uses laptop internet when connected with usb

Tags: lumia, 7.5, internet

Since yesterday, I have disabled mobile internet on my phone since my data ran out. Just a while ago when I connected my mobile to laptop to sync with Zune, I received mail on my phone. Later I browsed Internet Explorer and WhatsApp. Everything worked great. Therefore, I rechecked the mobile network to see if it was off. And yes, it was still off.

Then I realized it might be using my laptop connection which is connected to a LAN network for internet browsing.

So, my question is what happens to mobile internet connectivity when it's connected to a laptop. Does it automatically use any available net connection from the laptop, or just the via-LAN internet?

Answer (score 6):

Windows Phone uses your computer's internet connection only when the Zune software is open and connected to your phone. Your internet connection is then shared to your phone via Zune.

Comment: Source: http://pocketnow.com/windows-phone/zune-software-shares-its-internet-to-windows-phone-7-device

Comment: great. Glad I discovered it. Else until now I was first starting the WiFi hotspot on laptop and then using it.